# I want to schedule a Sendgrid mail to go at a certain time

Tags: email, sendgrid, filemaker

There are Sendgrid parameters to do this, but where do you put them in the Filemaker Send Mail function?  Can anyone help me on that?  Thanks.

Comment: I would guess you need to use the `Insert From URL` script step instead?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.